# Gensim Doc2Vec - Why does infer_vector() use alpha?

Tags: gensim, embedding, sentence, doc2vec

I try to map sentences to a vector in order to make sentences comparable to each other. To test gensim's Doc2Vec model, I downloaded sklearn's newsgroup dataset and trained the model on it.

In order to compare two sentences, I use model.infer_vector() and I am wondering why two calls using the same sentence delivers me different vectors:

```
model = Doc2Vec(vector_size=100, window=8, min_count=5, workers=6)
model.build_vocab(documents)

epochs=10
for epoch in range(epochs):
    print("Training epoch %d" % (epoch+1))
    model.train(documents,  total_examples=len(documents), epochs=epochs)

    v1 = model.infer_vector("I feel good")
    v2 = model.infer_vector("I feel good")
    print(np.linalg.norm(v1-v2))
```

Output:

> Training epoch 1
>
> 0.41606528
>
> Training epoch 2
>
> 0.43440753
>
> Training epoch 3
>
> 0.3203116
>
> Training epoch 4
>
> 0.3039317
>
> Training epoch 5
>
> 0.68224543
>
> Training epoch 6
>
> 0.5862567
>
> Training epoch 7
>
> 0.5424634
>
> Training epoch 8
>
> 0.7618142
>
> Training epoch 9
>
> 0.8170159
>
> Training epoch 10
>
> 0.6028216

If I set alpha and min_alpha = 0 I get consistent vectors for the "I feel fine" and "I feel good", but the model gives me the same vector in every epoch, so it does not seem to learn anything:

> Training epoch 1
>
> 0.043668125
>
> Training epoch 2
>
> 0.043668125
>
> Training epoch 3
>
> 0.043668125
>
> Training epoch 4
>
> 0.043668125
>
> Training epoch 5
>
> 0.043668125
>
> Training epoch 6
>
> 0.043668125
>
> Training epoch 7
>
> 0.043668125
>
> Training epoch 8
>
> 0.043668125
>
> Training epoch 9
>
> 0.043668125
>
> Training epoch 10
>
> 0.043668125

So my questions are:

1. Why do I even have the possibility to specify a learning rate for inference? I would expect that the model is only changed during training and not during inference.
2. If I specify alpha=0 for inference, why does the distance between those two vectors not change during different epochs?

Answer (score 5):

Inference uses an `alpha` because it is the same iterative adjustment process as training, just limited to updating the one new vector for the one new text example.

So yes, the model's various weights are frozen. But the one new vector's weights (dimensions) start at small random values, just as every other vector also began, and then get incrementally nudged over multiple training cycles to make the vector work better as a doc-vector for predicting the text's words. Then the final new-vector is returned.

Those nudges begin at the larger starting `alpha` value, and wind up as the negligible `min_alpha`. With an `alpha` at 0.0, no training/inference can happen, because every nudge-correction to the updatable weights is multiplied by 0.0 before it's applied, meaning no change happens.

Separate from that, your code has a number of problems that may prevent desirable results:

- By calling `train()` `epochs` times in a loop, and then also supplying a value larger than 1 for `epochs`, you're actually performing `epochs * epochs` total training passes
- further, by leaving `alpha` and `min_alpha` unspecified, each call to `train()` will descend the effective alpha from its high-value to its low-value each call – a sawtooth pattern that's not proper for this kind of stochastic gradient descent optimization. (There should be a warning in your logs about this error.)

It's rare to need to call `train()` multiple times in a loop. Just call it once, with the right `epochs` value, and it will do the right thing: that many passes, with a smoothly-decaying `alpha` learning-rate.

Separately, when calling `infer_vector()`:

- it needs a list-of-tokens, just like the `words` property of the training examples that were items in `documents` – *not* a string. (By supplying a string, it looks like a list-of-characters, so it will be inferring a doc-vector for the document `['I', ' ', 'f', 'e', 'e', 'l', ' ', 'g', 'o', 'o', 'd']` *not* `['I', 'feel', 'good']`.)
- those tokens should be preprocessed the same as the training documents – for example if they were lowercased there, they should be lowercased before passing to `infer_vector()`
- the default argument `passes=5` is very small, especially for short texts – many report better results with a value in the tens or hundreds
- the default argument `alpha=0.1` is somewhat large compared to the training default 0.025; using the training value (especially with more `passes`) often gives better results

Finally, just like the algorithm during training makes use of randomization (to adjust word-prediction context windows, or randomly-sample negative examples, or randomly down-sample highly-frequent words), the inference does as well. So even supplying the exact same tokens won't automatically yield the exact same inferred-vector.

However, if the model has been sufficiently-trained, and the inference is adjusted as above for better results, the vectors for the same text should be very, very close. And because this is a randomized algorithm with some inherent 'jitter' between runs, it's best to make your downstream evaluations and uses tolerant to such small variances. (And, if you're instead seeing large variances, correct other model/inference issues, usually with more data or other parameter adjustments.)

If you want to *force* determinism, there's some discussion of how to do that in a [gensim project issue](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/447). But, understanding & tolerating the small variances is often more consistent with the choice of such a randomly-influenced algorithm.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I did what you suggested, but get very poor results. I guess I have just bad training data... What would be a dataset that contains enough sentences to train a model with good results? I trained with the Stanford Treebank for 100 epochs (also tried 5 or 20, not much difference). For example, the sentences "I like you" and "I hate you" have a similar distance as "I like you" and "I love you" with my current model

Comment: Maybe I have some misunderstandings. Do the sentences that I use to train have to be related to each other or can I just use massive amounts of random sentences? What preprocessing steps should be done? Removing punctuation, stopwords, etc.?

Comment: No matter which datasets I try, the results are really far from good. Can you recommend a data set?

Comment: It's common to case-flatten tokens, and break words from punctuation – but word2vec/doc2vec varies on whether it removes stop words, keeps-or-drops punctuation tokens, etc. What's good training data depends on your goals, but you can use extra data for which you don't have labels to potentially improve the model's perception of words/texts, but then just learn the classification-distinctions-of-interest from the subset of docs for which you have labels. The original 'Paragraph Vectors' paper did this, and it's shown in the gensim demo `doc2vec-IMDB.ipynb` notebook, too.

Comment: The fact that distance("I like you", "I love you") and distance("I like you", "I hate you") are similar isn't *necessarily* a problem – it depends on your aims. It's possible (though not guaranteed) that *relative directions* of docs still capture an aspect-of-interest – for example, in certain directions are mostly negative feelings, and in others mostly positive. That's something a downstream classifier, trained on the doc-positions using known-sentiments, might be able to tease out, essentially learning subtle boundaries in the high-dimensional space better than your intuitive eyeballing.

Comment: My overall goal is to detect paraphrases, so 'I like you' should be far away from 'I hate you'. I am looking into recursive autoencoders now, they seem better to me, at least what I can see from the papers.